# Не отображаются картинки сайта на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css, wordpress

При переносе сайта на хостинг возникла проблема: не отображаются картинки во всех браузерах мобильных устройств. Причем на эмуляторе мобильных устройств в панели разработчика все выглядит корректно. Сайт создан на WordPress. Вот ссылка http://portal4web.ru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас и в desktop браузере никакие картинки не отображаются. Не отображаются они потому, что имеют пути вида

```
<img src="http://myportfolio/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/cropped-avatar3.jpg" class="round icon">
```

Вы видите сайт с картинками с локального компьютера, потому что у вас локально существует адрес `http://myportfolio`. А мобила этого адреса знать не знает.

Вывод - сайт перенесён неправильно. Почитайте о том, [как надо делать это правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562).

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы мне очень помогли. Плагин кэшировал страницу на desktop и я не увидел очевидного!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.